# Python multidimensional list to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

How can I write a multidimensional list to csv file in python.
I tried something like this:

```
with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter= ',')
    wtr.writerows(mylist)
```

or this:

```
i = 1
while i < len(mylist):
    input = os.path.join(folder, str((i-1)) + '_development)
    with open(input,'r') as csvinput:
        output = os.path.join(folder, str(i) + '_development)
        with open(output, 'w') as csvoutput:
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
            for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
                writer.writerow(row+mylist[i])
    os.remove(input)
    i +=1
```

But then the csv file has only one column.

My list:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

The output should look like this:

[image: table]

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transpose your list input first:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
l = zip(*l)
```

you will get:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

then call `writerows()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the zip comment i get the same list but i still have one column instead of two in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the `'wb'` flag? If you are using Python 3, you need to include `newline=''` as well:

**Edit:**

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in mylist:
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Depends on the python version.

Comment: @Whiteneon What does? Which version are you using?

Comment: My bad should have note it in the tags. I´m using python 2.7. The newline parameter is for version higher than 3.

Comment: Did not work for me. I get one column with 12 rows. After a row with a follows a blank row

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l).T # construct data frame and transpose

df.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False, sep=',')
```

Same code should work for python 2.7 and 3.X and pandas version > 0.19.